# Offset two child-charts within a VictoryChart

Tags: victory-charts

I have a boxplot and a scatterplot within a VictoryChart and want them shifted a number of pixels in the non-domain axis.

My current code and resulting chart are here: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-violet-opclp?file=/index.js

Now I want the red triangle to be placed a bit higher, so about 15 pixels in the y-direction upwards. I tried padding, domainPadding, dx, dy, but nothing works really.

Any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

By creating a [custom point](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/guides/custom-components/#creating-new-components), the actual position can be set. See https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-lederberg-i8ddx?file=/index.js